# I have Canadian refugee travel documents. Can I enter the United States?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, borders, refugees

Can I enter the US with my Canadian refugee travel documents? Do I need to apply for an ESTA or do I just show it at the port of entry like a regular Canadian citizen? I’ll probably drive in or take the train to cross the border :)
Also, would this be linked to my old past passport?

Answer (score 6):

> Can I enter the US with my Canadian refugee travel documents?

Yes.

> Do I need to apply for an ESTA or do I just show it at the port of entry like a regular Canadian citizen?

Neither.  You need a visa.

> Also, would this be linked to my old past passport?

They'll take your fingerprints, so yes.

Comment: I presume this answer is correct. But since the visa requirement seems to against the OPs expectations, the answer could be improved by explaining *why* (i.e. according to which laws and regulations) a refugee with Canadian refugee travel documents is treated differently that a Canadian citizen when it comes to entering the US.